# Is there a way in MvvmCross to force re-start the app and show the MvxSplash screen

Tags: mvvmcross

Is there a way in MvvmCross to force restart the application i.e. go back to the splash screen and reset any internal mvvmcross state e.g. associated viewmodel navigation etc.